# GridView Adapter not Displaying Data

Tags: android, xml, gridview, mobile, android-arrayadapter

Hello I have written a `GridView` Adapter which should correctly display one image and one title from  `FireBaseStorage`.

I have checked and verified that my Bitmap and title are correctly being retrieved. I instantiate the `GridView` and Adapter when a "place" is selected in `PlaceActivity`.

I get Data in my `getData`() method in Place Activity. My `GridView` is also inside a Swipe Refresh Layout in Place Activity XML. Any ideas? thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)        {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) data.get(position);
    if(item.getTitle() != null)
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    else
    holder.imageTitle.setText("Test");

    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
}


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageMetadata;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Place p;
    private AutocompleteFilter typeFilter;
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private Bitmap b;
    private String t;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        1);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }



        Intent i = getIntent();
        p = null;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
        typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                .build();

        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {

                        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                        myUpdateOperation();
                    }
                }
        );
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    } else {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlaceActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);


                    }
                }


                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Upload.class);
                if(p==null)
                {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Select a location!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else {
                    i.putExtra("folder", p.getName());

                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                return true;

            case R.id.search:
                // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
                // as a favorite...
                try {
                    Intent intent =
                            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                                    .build(this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                }


                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                p = place;
                gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_View);
                gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
                gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);


            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

public void myUpdateOperation()
{
    if(p==null)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Select a location!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridView.invalidateViews();
    GridViewAdapter gridAdapter2 = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter2);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}


    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child((String) p.getName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(myUrl);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    HashMap<String,String> m  = (HashMap<String, String>) iter.next().getValue();
                String v = m.get("url");
                    Log.d("url",v);

                    String bu = m.get("bucket");
                    Log.d("bucket",bu);
                    StorageReference iR = httpsReference.child(bu).child("thumb");

                    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
                    iR.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
                            b=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0, bytes.length);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                        }
                    });


                    httpsReference.child(bu).getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                            // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
                            t = storageMetadata.getCustomMetadata("title");
                            Log.d("title", t);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            Log.d("error", "ERROr");
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        }
                    });



                    imageItems.add(new ImageItem(b, t));




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return imageItems;
    }





}
```

**Place_Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="50dp">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_View"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id ="@+id/fab"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
    </FrameLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Grid Item Layout XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
getCount(){
  return data.size();
}
```

inside your adapter.

Your adapter is never calling getView() because you don't specify how many views you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I added these lines to the Adapter. But still nothing is displayed?                                                                                                            @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return data.size();
    }

Comment: I read your code again and there are multiple issues with it. First thing in your getData() method. That is working async. So for you, it returns the empty array before adding any items to it. So instead of that you should make it a void function, and when you get a new item add it directly to the adapter array, and call notifyDataSetChanged. I will write a complete answer tonight when I get home if I don't forget

Comment: Thank you! I would really appreciate that.